# Flex/Flash Event Question

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, events

I am trying to get the event data in a event handler..my debugger image is as follow:[alt text http://www.popslinger.org/debug2.JPG](http://www.popslinger.org/debug2.JPG)

I tried to dispatch my custom event with the `event.data`
please see onPlayerError function...

My debug shows my data value is -1 but the compile said 
"access of undefined property data throught a reference with a static type flash.events.event"

Not sure what to do here..Please help me...Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the trace statement in the comment. You need to cast your event as an Object
like this: 
Object(event).data